# Self-reference column in sqlalchemy core

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/self_referential.html explains how a table's column can refer to the table in the ORM. How can a column refer to its containing table in SQLAlchemy Core?

For example, this won't work because `person` isn't defined yet at the time it needs to be referenced.

```
import sqlalchemy as sa


metadata = sa.MetaData()

person = sa.Table(
    "person",
    metadata,
    sa.Column("person_id", sa.BigInteger, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True),
    sa.Column("mother", None, sa.ForeignKey(person.c.person_id)),
)                                         # ^ This is an errror
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the string argument form of [`ForeignKey`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/constraints.html#sqlalchemy.schema.ForeignKey), i.e. `'tablename.columnkey'`:

```
person = sa.Table(
    "person",
    metadata,
    sa.Column("person_id", sa.BigInteger, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True),
    sa.Column("mother", sa.ForeignKey("person.person_id")),  # Note: no `.c.`
)
```

The string argument is handled lazily, so that it can reference for example tables from other modules without having to import them, as long as they exist in the metadata. In this case it allows referencing the table itself.